# How to make a Header that Animates from Transparent to Opaque Color on Scrolling down in React-Native React Navigation 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to make header that will animate from transparent to solid opaque color upon scrolling down using in React-Native [React Navigation 5](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2020/02/06/react-navigation-5.0/).

Starts to transition to opaque when scrolling halfway

[image]

---

Becomes fully opaque when reach the maximum offset

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by setting the header style opacity to an animated value.

First define your animated value, we'll interpolate the yOffset to get the opacity desired.

```
const yOffset = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
const headerOpacity = yOffset.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 200],
  outputRange: [0, 1],
  extrapolate: "clamp",
});
```

then you want to attach an animated.event listener to an animated scroll view

```
<Animated.ScrollView
  onScroll={Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: {
            y: yOffset,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    { useNativeDriver: true }
  )}
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
>
```

Your content should be inside the scroll view

In your screen add a on mount or use effect where you set the animatedValue as the header opacity

```
useEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerStyle: {
      opacity: headerOpacity,
    },
    headerBackground: () => (
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "white",
          ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
          opacity: headerOpacity,
        }}
      />
    ),
    headerTransparent: true,
  });
}, [headerOpacity, navigation]);
```

I've used header transparent and header background so that the background component changes also.

Here is an example:

https://snack.expo.io/@dannyhw/react-navigation-animated-header

Comment: Hi, could you also guide me on how to transition the back arrow button?

Comment: I tried this >
headerLeft: (props) => (                                                     
              <Icon                       
              name='arrowleft'
              type='antdesign'
              color='white'
              size={24}                            
              containerStyle={{borderRadius:500, backgroundColor: headerOpacity, padding: 5, marginLeft:10}}
              {...props}
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.goBack();
              }}
              />                                                       
    )

Comment: but it is resulting to RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. This error is located at: in Themed.Icon

Comment: Hey tamashi, I'll have a look. I saw you made another question I'll answer there.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! For anyone who gets the error message "Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render", note that the useEffect needs to be called AFTER the yOffset/headerY variable inits.

Comment: Hi, i currently implemented this solution and its working. but my problem is when the header is not shown, im created my back button for users to press to go back. The button cannot be pressed because it is within the height of the header

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleScroll = () => {
  YourElementRef.current.style.backgroundColor = `rgba(245, 245, 245, ${window.scrollY > 300 ? 1 : '0.' + (window.scrollY * 3)})`;
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, true);
```

You need to add scroll listener and call function that animates it.
The scroll element is represented by a ref stuff. e.g.

```
const YourElementRef = React.useRef(null);
<SomeElement ref={YourElementRef}...
```

Comment: This would work on plain React.js, but not React Native. It's quite different to implement animation to native apps from web.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Danny's answer to implement the header animation successfully.

I wanted to share my solution for implementing the animation **for the header title**:

1. Wrap Animated.Header around a Text component (the text will be the header title):

   ```
    useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: "", 
      headerStyle: {
        opacity: headerOpacity,
      },
      headerBackground: () => (
        <Animated.View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "white",
            ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
            opacity: headerOpacity,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>This is the Title</Text>
        </Animated.View>
      ),
      headerTransparent: true,
    });
    }, [headerOpacity, navigation]);
   ```
2. Use these styles to mimic native iOS header title styles:

   ```
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headerTitle: {
      fontSize: 17,
      fontWeight: "600",
      bottom: 12,
      textAlign: "center",
      flex: 1,
      position: "absolute",
      width: "100%",
    }, 
    })
   ```